# SQLite database file not found

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, jquery-mobile, adt

I have here a working jquery-mobile code that creates an SQLite database and automatically inputs everytime the app is launched.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css"></link>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.simpledialog.min.css" />     
    <script type="text/javascript" href="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile.simpledialog2.min.js"></script>        



    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        var db = "";
        db = window.openDatabase("Dummy_DB", "1.0", "Just a Dummy DB", 200000); //will create database Dummy_DB or open it
        db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);


    //create table and insert some record
    function populateDB(tx) {
        //tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SoccerPlayer');   
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SoccerPlayer (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name TEXT NOT NULL, Club TEXT NOT NULL)');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SoccerPlayer(Name,Club) VALUES ("Alexandre Pato", "AC Milan")');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SoccerPlayer(Name,Club) VALUES ("Van Persie", "Arsenal")');
    }

    //function will be called when an error occurred
    function errorCB(err) {
        alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
    }

    //function will be called when process succeed
    function successCB() {
        alert("success!");
        db.transaction(queryDB,errorCB);
    }

    //select all from SoccerPlayer
    function queryDB(tx){
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM SoccerPlayer',[],querySuccess,errorCB);
    }

    function querySuccess(tx,result){
        var playerlist = document.getElementById("SoccerPlayerList");
        var players = "";
        alert("The show is on");
        var len = result.rows.length;
        for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
            alert(result.rows.item(i).Name + result.rows.item(i).Club);
            players = players + '<li><a href="#"><p class="record">'+result.rows.item(i).Name+'</p><p class="small">Club '+result.rows.item(i).Club+'</p></a></li>';
        }   

        playerlist.innerHTML = players;
        $("#SoccerPlayerList").listview("refresh");

    }
    </script>

</head>

<body>

<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
    <h1>Soccer Player</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
     <ul id="SoccerPlayerList">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!--end of Soccer Player Page--->
</body>

</html>
```

My problem is i cannot locate the database file itself within the File Explorer under DDMS. I have read that it is located under data/data//databases but it only contains these:
[image]

the database Dummy_DB should be there. Is there something wrong? I am sure that Dummy_DB and its contents really exist as i have launched the app over and over again and the listview contents keep on populating everytime i launch the app.

Here is the output after launching and closing the app 4 times within the emulator:
[image]

I am really confused right now as this is my first time learing SQLite with jquery-mobile. Any help will be gladly accepted, thanks in advance.

I am using eclipse ADT as my emulator.

Comment: you forgot to add `data-role="listview"` to `ul`.

Answer (score 0):

**Write this**

db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({"name" : "Dummy_DB"});

**Instead of**

db = window.openDatabase("Dummy_DB", "1.0", "Just a Dummy DB", 200000);